# How can I change root password via ansible to ~30 hosts?

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I need to update more than 30 hosts the root password. 
I read that I can user user module for that... but I'm doing something wrong.

Can you drop some help here ?

Comment: Please, show what code you already have.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

Typo in above yaml file .

```
- name: Password rollover
  user:
      name: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"   ## Should not have "-"
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ lookup('env', 'PASSWORD') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation and what I did to solve it was a playbook like this:

```
Filename: password_rollover.yml

---

- name: Password rollover
  user:
    - name: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ lookup('env', 'PASSWORD') }}"
```

You use it passing those env variables:

```
USER=root PASSWORD=newpass ansible-playbook --limit group password_rollover.yml -b
```